# git-svn dcommit error: unable to determine upstream SVN information

Tags: git-svn

I m trying out git-svn and I am getting the following error. What I've done so far is

```
 git svn init -T <my svn repo>
```

then I've been committing to my repository with

```
 git commit -a
```

then once I did a few of those I did a

```
 git svn fetch
```

and then I tried a

```
 git svn dcommit
```

However, that fails with

> Unable to determine the upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
>   Perhaps the repository is empty

I can also see that the files in my file system are not marked as being used by svn (not sure if this should happen or not) though. If I browse the svn repository (with repo browser) I can see that the original files are there.

After this original failure I tried **rebasing** without much success (it throws some other error).

Comment: I assume this is related to the fact, that the SVN repository is empty at the beginning. Not sure whether this is a limitation of git-svn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git svn` commands are similar to dealing with a normal remote (the svn remote is named `git-svn`). `fetch` just downloads commits from the remote, it doesn't connect them to your tree in any way. It will work if you fetch right after initing, since you don't have a tree yet, but you committed first. You want to use `git svn rebase`, which will rebase your tree onto the svn head. Normally you `git svn fetch` right after `git svn init`, or just use `git svn clone`, which does both. Once the initial repository is set up you can just use `git svn rebase` all the time, which fetches and rebases in one operation

Comment: hi Michael. thanks for the explanation . I didnt know that I needed to rebase before starting committing to the git repo . I tried giot svn rebase (as i said in my post) but it throws Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree dictionary

Comment: @Miau I'm not sure how to fix your existing repository; you may need to create a new one and set up the svn remote properly *before* you commit anything

Comment: One thing you could do is try saving your commits as patches and then do a `git reset --hard`. Then do `git svn fetch` and `git svn rebase` to get the upstream updates. Then apply your patches and commit. This **may** work.

Answer (score 3):

I found that, when the SVN repo was empty git-svn throws

> Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history

So using SVN I checked in a text file as the first commit

```
svn add test.txt; svn commit -m "test file"
```

Then I was able to do a git svn clone and that fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

This site fixed the issue for me: http://eikke.com/importing-a-git-tree-into-a-subversion-repository/. Direct quote:

> The issue is that the SVN metadata has been lost. To fix this, we can
>   use a Git graft to link them. We’ll tell Git the commit which created
>   the SVN folder in which we want to store the project is the parent
>   commit of the first commit in our Git repository:

```
$ git show-ref trunk 
> 741ab63aea786882eafd38dc74369e651f554c9c refs/remotes/trunk 
$ $ git log --pretty=oneline master | tail -n1
> 88464cfdf549a82b30ee7c52e53e2b310f0d9ec4 Initial version  
$ echo "88464cfdf549a82b30ee7c52e53e2b310f0d9ec4 741ab63aea786882eafd38dc74369e651f554c9c" >> .git/info/grafts`
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a general `git-svn` limitation? Or exists the problem between keyboard and chair?

This error message was introduced in git 1.5.1 (Feb. 2007) by [commit a8ae262](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8ae26235ced15d8ce129a8ff72c558b8a567813)

> Since you're committing from HEAD (or another commit that is a parent of HEAD), you'll be able to find a commit with metadata information containing the SVN URL that your HEAD was descended from anyways.

So git needs to find a commit including the SVN URL in order for a dcommit of one of your branch to work properly.

> Or exists the problem between keyboard and chair?

That can happen if you select one of your branch created *before* `git svn clone`. You need to work with branches created on top of the ones imported from SVN by `git svn clone`.

Comment: With other words: Git-svn cannot handle empty Subversion repositories.

Comment: @usr1234567 indeed, that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, try **git svn clone**, then change/commit files, then **git svn dcommit**. This is the way I usually do it and it works (in my case).

Comment: Does this also work with a SVN repository, that hasN#t got any commit yet?